# 3d point cloud via multiple images turns out to be several lines

Tags: java, android, opencv, computer-vision

[3D point cloud shows in Matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF8gx.png)

[Original object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEgdB.jpg)

This is my Android app which does 3D reconstruction on cell phone. The result of 
the reconstruction is like this. The 3D points are lining up and stretching to different directions...I`ve tried for days and cannot solve this problem. Thank you in advance! The feature and matching algorithm is Pyramid_ORB

```
        //out1 and out2 are two ArrayList that contain all the filtered feature points
        MatOfPoint2f matpoints1 = new MatOfPoint2f(out1.toArray(new Point[0]));
        MatOfPoint2f matpoints2 = new MatOfPoint2f(out2.toArray(new Point[0]));

        Size msize = new Size();
        msize.height=3;
        msize.width=3;
        Mat cam = new Mat(msize,CV_64FC1);
        double arr[] = {853.53285,0,476.32870,0,1132.35572,363.97813,0,0,1};
        cam.put(0,0,arr);
        msize.height=4;
        msize.width=1;
        Mat dist = new Mat(msize, CV_64FC1);
        double arr2[] = {0.08580, -0.22893, -0.00541, -0.00221};
        dist.put(0,0,arr2);
        MatOfDouble distCoeffs = new MatOfDouble(dist);
        Mat outpoints = new Mat();
        //if it were the first two picture then use essential matrix to get RT and point cloud
        if(count < 2){
            if(pointsize < 5){
                count = 0;
            }
            else{
                Mat essen = Calib3d.findEssentialMat(matpoints1, matpoints2, cam);
                Mat rot2 = new Mat();
                Mat t2 = new Mat();
                ArrayList<Mat> matlist = new ArrayList<Mat>();
                ArrayList<Mat> pRes = new ArrayList<Mat>();
                PointCloud pc = new PointCloud(essen, pointsize);
                pRes = pc.getPointCloud(cam,reR,reT,img1,img2);
                flag = true;
                //The Projection matrix save for next triangulation, outpoint is the Mat of point cloud
                reProj = pRes.get(0);
                outpoints = pRes.get(1);
            }
        }

        else{
            //Else use PnP to get R and t matrix
            int indexOfCloud = cloud.size()-1;
            ArrayList<Integer> queryIdx = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> out2Idx = new ArrayList<>();
            Mat lastOut3Dpoint = cloud.get(indexOfCloud);
            //This loop get the index of 3d point in last 3d point cloud
            //and the corresponding 2d coordinates of the previous right image
            //out1 and out2 here have been re-ordered before to let out1.get(i) is corresponse to out2.get(i)
            for(int i = 0;i < out1.size();i++){
                Point tempP = out1.get(i);
                Integer n = lastPoint.get(tempP);
                if(n!=null){
                    queryIdx.add(n);
                    out2Idx.add(i);
                }
            }
            //Break here if out2Idx.size() < 4, then use new pic
            if(out2Idx.size() < 4){
                flag = false;
                Log.d("out2idxsize", out2Idx.size()+"");
            }

            //end of renew
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enough Point for PnP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                List<Point3> inputP = new ArrayList<Point3>();
                double tem[] = new double[3];
                for(int i = 0;i<queryIdx.size();i++){
                    Point3 p3 = new Point3();
                    lastOut3Dpoint.col(queryIdx.get(i)).get(0,0,tem);
                    p3.x=tem[0];
                    p3.y=tem[1];
                    p3.z=tem[2];
                    inputP.add(i,p3);
                }
                MatOfPoint3f pt = new MatOfPoint3f();
                pt.fromList(inputP);
                //End of objPoint

                //Get the imgPoint ready
                List<Point> inputP2 = new ArrayList<Point>();

                for(int i = 0;i<out2Idx.size();i++){
                    inputP2.add(i, out2.get(out2Idx.get(i)));
                }
                MatOfPoint2f pt2 = new MatOfPoint2f();
                pt2.fromList(inputP2);
                //End of imgPoint

                RtMatrix pnpRt = new RtMatrix(cam, distCoeffs);
                ArrayList<Mat> Rtm = pnpRt.getRtMatrix(pt, pt2);
                ProjMatrix proj_second = new ProjMatrix(Rtm.get(0),Rtm.get(1));
                Mat proj_2 = proj_second.getProjMatrix(cam);
                Mat unNormalize = new Mat();
                Calib3d.triangulatePoints(reProj, proj_2, img1, img2, unNormalize);
                //Later this part will fuse into the class PointCloud
                int numofPoint = unNormalize.width();
                double hoc[]= new double[numofPoint];
                unNormalize.get(3,0,hoc);
                Size vect = new Size();
                vect.height = 4;
                vect.width = 4;
                ArrayList<Mat>outList = new ArrayList<Mat>();
                double invHoc;
                for(int j = 0;j < numofPoint;j++){
                    Mat tempHoc = new Mat(vect, CV_64FC1);
                    invHoc = 1/hoc[j];
                    double inputHoc[] = {invHoc,0.0,0,0,0,invHoc,0,0,0,0,invHoc,0,0,0,0,invHoc};
                    tempHoc.put(0,0,inputHoc);
                    Mat horTemp = new Mat();
                    Core.gemm(tempHoc, unNormalize.col(j), 1, Mat.zeros(tempHoc.size(), tempHoc.type()), 0, horTemp);
                    outList.add(horTemp);
                }
                Core.hconcat(outList, outpoints);
                reProj = proj_2;
                tb.print3DMat(outpoints, "pnpOut");
                //End of fuse
                flag = true;

            }
        }
        return outputImg;
```

Comment: Can you add the codes?

Comment: Of course! Here it is

Comment: Can you please share the intermediate results like Calibration error, reprojection error, feature matching etc... because the pipeline for 3D reconstruction has many steps and error in one step will compound the error a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Way too many things that could be wrong there. The bad triangulations you see could be the effect of false matches, or or of so-so matches with a very short baseline and nearly parallel rays.

You need to visualize the triangulated matches reprojecting them back into the images to see what's going on.

Comment: I can see the Match result and it is good enough, I use ransac to filter the match point, can anything else to be wrong?  I`m new to SFM, can you recommand me an algorithm or function to visualize them? Thank you for your suggestion!